# Example problem of induced emf in a coil rotating in the earth's magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, coil, induction, emf, formula-derivation

I just recently learned magnetism-coil-faraday's law and I want to do some real world problem solving.

**Question**: Let's say a copper wire coil (20 mm dimeter (***r=10 mm***)) of 3 turns (***N=3***) is on the surface of the earth rotating around itself (**Edit**: Spinning) at the speed of ***300 rotations/sec***; The magnetic field strength of the earth (***|B|=60e-6 T***) are passing through the coil; How much emf will be induced in the rotating (**Edit**: Spinning) coil?  **Edit**: (assume load ***R=3 Ω***)

**Answer**:
$$emf = -N \times\frac{d(\phi)}{dt} volts$$

Let's find the magnetic flux φ first,
θ is the angle between the magnetic field B and the coil's surface.

$$Magnetic \space flux = B*A \times cos(\theta) Wb$$
$$\phi = ( 60e-6 )\times( \pi (10e-3)^2 )\times(cos(\theta))$$
$$\phi = ( 5.921e-8 )*(cos(\theta)) Wb$$

Now, let's how much magnetic flux φ is changing with respect to time,

$$\frac{d(\phi)}{dt} = ( 5.921e-8 )\times\frac{ d(cos(\theta)}{dt}$$
$$\frac{d(\phi)}{dt} = ( 5.921e-8 )\times( -sin(\theta)) \times\frac{d(\theta)}{dt}$$

Now, we need to find out how fast the angle θ is changing,
the coil is rotating at the speed of 300 rotation/sec so 300[rotation]*360(degrees) per second which is equal to ***10.8e+4*** degrees per second.
hence,

$$\frac{d(\phi)}{dt} = -( 6.394e-3 )sin(\theta) $$

Now, let's calculate induced emf,

$$Induced \space emf = -( 3 )\times( -( 6.394e-3 )sin(\theta) )$$
$$Induced \space emf = 19.184sin(\theta) mV $$
$$Induced \space current = 6.394sin(\theta) mA$$
__(assume R=3 Ω)

I think I made a mistake while calculating the rate of change of angle θ?

*Is the answer correct?*

Comment: Use radians instead of degrees.

Comment: Current is not induced. It depends on the ( unspecified) load across the coil.

Comment: *rotating around itself* <-- this does not explain how the coil rotates relative the the magnetic field.

Comment: @Andyaka I meant spinning. But I edited it now.

Comment: @RussellH Now I added int the Edit, load R=3 ohm. Seeing 2 flags on your comment is it because I Edited the question after you told me there is load unspecified?

Comment: I can't answer for them. I suspect it is about how current is created in the coil @yssh. It is not induced, only voltage is induced.

Comment: @RussellH Are you saying there will not be current flow in the coil even now it is connected to a 3 ohm load resistor?

Comment: The current exists because of the induced voltage placed across the load. Current does not appear in Faraday's law, so is not considered to be induced. Of course there is current with the load resistor as I have indicated @yssh.

Comment: Do I have to use any other law to find induced current? @RussellH Is it lenz's law?